# How to change image on hover using tailwind css?

Tags: css, image, hover, tailwind-css

What class should I use for changing the image when I hover over it using tailwind css?
Using normal vanilla CSS I could assign a class to the image and the use

```
.class:hover{ background:url("....jpg");}
```

to change but I cant find an alternative for this in tailwind.

Answer (score 2):

I made this, pass the image into a variable and import like this, after this, just pass the variable of image in the src.

```
    import FinantoLogo from '../static/images/FinantoLogo.png'
    import teste from '../static/images/test.jpg'
    
 

<div class="flex flex-wrap mt-24">
  <div class="w-1/2 ml-16">
    <div class="mx-auto w-24 h-32 rounded-full ml-auto">
      <div class="relative">
        <img src={finantoPerfil} class="rounded-full transition-transform duration-300 transform hover:scale-110" alt="Imagem de perfil" />
        <img src={teste} class="rounded-full absolute top-0 left-0 opacity-0 transition-opacity duration-300 transform hover:opacity-100" alt="Nova imagem" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a special modifier for hover stuff in Tailwind, which can be applied to all utilities. Check out the docs here: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states

Here is a quick example:

```html
<div class="bg-foo hover:bg-bar">
  Hover me to change img
</div>
```

```
.bg-foo {
  background:url("foo.jpg");
}

.hover\:bg-bar:hover {
  background:url("bar.jpg");
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This is again the CSS version of it right? I tried it out using vanilla CSS and it works but I can't find the alternative in tailwind. There are properties to change background-colour etc. on hover but not any for changing the image or displaying text overlay. Thanks for replying.

Comment: It's actually a bit of both! Yes, it's some extra css, but it's also the suggested way described by tailwind in their docs. There are indeed no built-in tailwind classes to do with natively and without any additional css.

Comment: To add, it does work a bit differently than pure css. As you can see, the class is `hover:bg-bar`, but that's not the same class used for styling. That's a tailwind feature.